# Why can't I insert my php login form into my site template?

Tags: php, html, authentication, insert

what is going on?
I recently installed and updated a site template , and designed it.
My friend had some site which he got on it a php login form, for users to log in.

I asked him for the code and he gave me it, and ofc I just copied the code and pasted it between my site template code.

I know u confused, so here's the deal:

This is a basic page on my site:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if(MODULE == 'none')
{
    include(LOVE_ROOT . '/system/love_head.php');
    $content = '<h2> Welcome to OUR SITE </h2>
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br /> <br />
Hey this is a test
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br /> <br />
Welcome
<br />
Welcome to our site
<br />
Hey this is a test
<br /> <br /> <br />    

        ';

    include(LOVE_ROOT . '/system/love_foot.php');
}
else
{
    header('Location: modules/' . MODULE);
}
?>
```

and here is the login form php code:

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
?> 
<html dir="rtl"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" /> 
<style> 
a:link,a:visited,a:active 
{ 
background: transparent; 

color: #000000; 

text-decoration: none; 
} 

a:hover 
{     
background: transparent; 

color: #00dfff; 
} 
td { 
border: 1px solid gray; 
padding: 5px; 
text-align: center; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
<center> 
<?php 
include('mysql.php'); 

$fname = $_POST['fname']; 
$password = $_POST['pass']; 

$pass1 = md5($password); 
$pass = sha1($pass1); 

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE fname='$fname'"); 
$cu = mysql_fetch_array($select); 

if (!empty($_COOKIE['adv_U']) AND !empty($_COOKIE['adv_P'])) 
{ 
echo "אתה כבר מחובר לתחרות."; 
} 
else 
{ 
if (!empty($username) || !empty($password)) 
{ 
if (empty($cu)) 
{ 
?> 
<font color="darkred"><b> 
שגיאה - השם  הפרטי שהכנסת לא קיים במערכת 
</b></font> 
<br><br> 
<input type="button" value="חזור אחורה" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:window.history.back(-1)';"> 
<?php 
} 
else if ($pass == $cu['password']) 
{ 
if ($cu['ban'] == 1) 
{ 
echo "<font color='red'><b>אתה מורחק מהתחרות עקב עבירה על החוקים!</b></font><br>אתה מוחזר לדף הבית של המערכת..."; 
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=index.php'>"; 
} 
else 
{ 
setcookie('adv_U',$fname); 
setcookie('adv_P',$pass); 
header( 'Location: index.php' ); 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
?> 
<font color="darkred"><b> 
הסיסמא שהכנסת שגויה 
</b></font> 
<br><br> 
<input type="button" value="חזור אחורה" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:window.history.back(-1)';"> 
<?php 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
?> 
<form method="post" action="login.php"> 
<table> 
<tr><td>שם פרטי</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr> 
<tr><td>סיסמא</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="התחברות"></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="2"><a href="signup.php">(עוד לא נרשמת?)</a></font></td></tr> 
</table> 
</form> 
<?php 
} 
} 
?> 
</div> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php 
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

I tried to copy the php code between the headers of my page, to something like that:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if(MODULE == 'none')
{
    include(LOVE_ROOT . '/system/love_head.php');
    $content = '<h2> Welcome to OUR SITE </h2>
<br />
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" />
<style>
a:link,a:visited,a:active
{
background: transparent;

color: #000000;

text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{   
background: transparent;

color: #00dfff;
}
td {
border: 1px solid gray;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<center>
<?php
include('mysql.php');

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$pass1 = md5($password);
$pass = sha1($pass1);

$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE fname='$fname'");
$cu = mysql_fetch_array($select);

if (!empty($_COOKIE['adv_U']) AND !empty($_COOKIE['adv_P']))
{
echo "אתה כבר מחובר לתחרות.";
}
else
{
if (!empty($username) || !empty($password))
{
if (empty($cu))
{
?>
<font color="darkred"><b>
שגיאה - השם  הפרטי שהכנסת לא קיים במערכת
</b></font>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="חזור אחורה" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:window.history.back(-1)';">
<?php
}
else if ($pass == $cu['password'])
{
if ($cu['ban'] == 1)
{
echo "<font color='red'><b>אתה מורחק מהתחרות עקב עבירה על החוקים!</b></font><br>אתה מוחזר לדף הבית של המערכת...";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3; url=index.php'>";
}
else
{
setcookie('adv_U',$fname);
setcookie('adv_P',$pass);
header( 'Location: index.php' );
}
}
else
{
?>
<font color="darkred"><b>
הסיסמא שהכנסת שגויה
</b></font>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="חזור אחורה" onclick="window.location.href='javascript:window.history.back(-1)';">
<?php
}
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="login.php">
<table>
<tr><td>שם פרטי</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>סיסמא</td><td><input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="התחברות"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="2"><a href="signup.php">(עוד לא נרשמת?)</a></font></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
}
?>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
<br /> <br /> <br />    

        ';

    include(LOVE_ROOT . '/system/love_foot.php');
}
else
{
    header('Location: modules/' . MODULE);
}
?>
```

Of course I handled all the problems, deleted php tags where it's not neccessery, closed qoutes and etc..

but still.. it just won't work.

Sorry for my English, 
Sorry for my lame knowledge,
please try and help a bummed guy who stuck with this problem already a week..

Thanks alot!

ALSO(!) I tried to fix it with NetBeans... but didn't manage.. lol I dont evenk now how this software works..

If I take the php code as it self, the original one, it works. If I take the original index file without anything else, it works.
When I add the code to the site template with the "love_foot" "love_head" and etc.. around the php login code, it tells me "unexpected T String".

So what is the problem here?

Thanks alot , I am so LOST right now!

Comment: `doesn't work`? -- you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Even if you manage to get this one resolved, you should really learn how to program and use proper tools. Take your time, read and make your fishing rod, instead of asking for fish.

Comment: as I said im still a newbie, which means I can't solve anything by myself. I know how to write codes, I know how HTML + PHP + CSS should work and sometimes even build sites by my own, but right now i'm stuck and looking for help, and you don't help so much.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the semicolon on Line 8. That's causing the rest of the PHP lines to be ignored.

Change it to:

```
$content = '<h2> Welcome to OUR SITE </h2><br />';
```

And around line ~127, you forgot to open the `<?` tag.

I believe that should fix the errors.

However you should use an IDE with syntax highlighting. That'll help you debug code faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really mean it. But the semicolon u told me to add doesn't change much, because it's says now: " unexpected '<' on line 9". I don't think this is the problem because in the original code, the first index page, it's also missing the semicolon but it works just fine.

Comment: By the way, I ran now my code in NetBeans, it's shows me that it's ok, everything is fine but the "unexpected '<'", it's says that after a semicolon I can't start a new <?php tag..